# XSL - Invalid Xpath Extension on Replace

Tags: xslt

Im getting on error when I try and use the following:

```
<xsl:variable name="url" select="guid"/>        
<xsl:variable name="vid" select="substring-after($url,'podcast/')"/>
<xsl:variable name="pre" select="substring-before($vid,'.mp4')"/>

<<xsl:variable name="p" select="replace($pre,'_','-')"/>
<xsl:variable name="p1" select="concat($p,'.embed_thumbnail.jpg')"/>
<xsl:variable name="p2" select="concat('http://images.ted.com/images/ted/tedindex/embed-posters/',$p1)"/>
```

Can anyone see a problem, it all looks good to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using an XSLT 1 processor? The [`replace`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace) function appeared in XPath 2.0 and is therefore not available in XSLT 1.

In this case you could just use the [`translate`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-translate) function instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra unescaped less-than sign before your `p` variable's definition:

```
<<xsl:variable name="p" select="replace($pre,'_','-')"/>
```

That's not valid syntax.

You should either remove it:

```
<xsl:variable name="p" select="replace($pre,'_','-')"/>
```

Or escape it:

```
&lt;<xsl:variable name="p" select="replace($pre,'_','-')"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a '<<' at the start of line 4, is that it?